# API data to Bar graph in .Net MAUI

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

Am trying to create an app in .Net MAUI, i click a button, it fetches data from https://montemagno.com/monkeys.json and display a bar graph using LiveCharts. The bar graph must show the monkey name on x axis and monkey population on y axis. I am using the library of LiveChartsCore.SkiaSharpView. The graph is not being drawing because i have error with BarSeries. I tried to do the same code to display the data in a list and it is working fine. So the code is feching the data from the API. But not drawing the graph. Can you please help me.

I wonder if there is another way to draw a graph?

My Code-behind

```
private List<Monkey> monkeys;

    //The graph
    public ISeries[] Series { get; set; } =
    {
        new ColumnSeries<double>
        {
            Values = new ChartValues<double>(),
            Fill = new SolidColorPaint(SKColors.BlueViolet)
        }
    };
    public Axis[] XAxes { get; set; } =
    {
        new Axis
        {
            Name = "Monkey Names",
            Labels = new string[] { }
        }
    };
    public Axis[] YAxes { get; set; } =
    {
        new Axis
        {
            Name = "Monkeys Population",
            Labels = new string[] { }
        }
    };
    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void FetchDataButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Fetch data
            //var client = new HttpClient();
            //var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://montemagno.com/monkeys.json");
            //var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Monkey>));
            //monkeys = serializer.ReadObject(stream) as List<Monkey>;


            var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var url = "https://montemagno.com/monkeys.json";
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url); //deserialize the JSON data into a List<Monkey> object 
            monkeys = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Monkey>>();

            var chartValues = new ChartValues<double>(); //is used to store the values of the chart, the population of the monkeys
            var labels = new string[monkeys.Count]; // string array that will store the X-axis of the chart. The size of the array is set to the number of monkeys in the list.
            
            //iterates through each monkey in the list of monkeys
            int i = 0;
            foreach (var monkey in monkeys)
            {
                chartValues.Add(monkey.Population);  //assigns the chartValues list to the Values property of the first series of the char
                labels[i] = monkey.Name; // assigns the labels array to the Labels property of the first X-axis of the chart.
                i++;
            }
            Series[0].Values = chartValues;
            XAxes[0].Labels = labels;
            PopulationChart.IsVisible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Error", "An error occured while fetching data", "OK");
        }

    }
    public class Monkey
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Population { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the xaml file

```
<ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Button Grid.Row="0"
                x:Name="FetchDataButton" 
                Text="Fetch Data" 
                Clicked="FetchDataButton_Clicked"/>

            <lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Row="1"
                                x:Name="PopulationChart"
                                IsVisible="False"
                                Series="{Binding Series}"
                                YAxes="{Binding YAxes}"
                                XAxes="{Binding XAxes}">
            </lvc:CartesianChart>

        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: "i have error" - what exactly is the error(s)?

Comment: The error is in (new BarSeries). This is the error message: Using the generic type 'BarSeries<TModel, TVisual, TLabel, TDrawingContext>' requires 4 type arguments

Comment: Have you looked at the docs?  Their bar chart sample does not use BarSeries

Comment: I have edited the code, now there are no errors! but when i click the button nothing happens. But if i use the commented fetch data, after i click the button i get the error message in the exception. I dont know where am going wrong

Comment: Where's the error message/exception? Why don't you provide it? This is not a place for guessing.